# How to apply pandas.qcut as part of the sqlalchemy query in python?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I am querying the table which returns specific columns, and based on these column values I need to update another column by checking the condition.
How can I apply `qcut` directly in sqlalchemy query?
Is it possible?

My quartile thresholds are:

```
2 -- A(updatable value)
4 -- B
5 -- C 
10 --D
```

I am having the query like this

> query=select([example_table.c.valueA,example_table.c.valueB])

It returns:

```
valueA  valueB
     5       3
     6       2 
     1       2
     3      10
```

I want the output, based on value A, to add another field with quartile value:

```
valueA  valueB  QuartileValueForA         
     5       3                  C
     6       2                  D
     1       2                  A
     3      10                  B
```

Is it possible through `qcut`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) (rather than quartile [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html)):

```
In [11]: pd.cut(df['valueA'], [-np.inf, 2, 4, 5, 10, np.inf], labels=list("ABCDE"))
Out[11]:
0    C
1    D
2    A
3    B
Name: valueA, dtype: category
Categories (5, object): [A < B < C < D < E]
```

Comment: Note:You can set this to a column with `df["QuartileValueForA"] = pd.cut(...)`

Comment: Thanks Andy Hayden.Can't I do it in a sqlalchemy query directly?

Comment: I don't think so.